# I wrote a function that is triggered by on edit (e) but need to have this run inside a larger function that is time driven

Tags: google-apps-script

My script runs perfectly when triggered by editing the spreadsheet. I am needing to rewrite this so that it can be called and ran inside a larger function that has an installable trigger set to run weekly. My skills are limited and I am having trouble figuring this out. Below is the code I need to modify.

```
function archiveIVABPO(e) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('IVA');
 const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Archived');
 const numColumnsToMove = 20;
 var Avals = sheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues();
 var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length; 
 const rangeToMove = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, Alast, numColumnsToMove);
 const values = rangeToMove.getValues();
 appendRowsV(targetSheet, values, 1);
 var vs = sheet.getRange('A3:T1500').setValue(null);
}
```

I see the two lines of code that reference "e"

```
const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Archived');
const rangeToMove = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, Alast, numColumnsToMove);
```

What I am unsure of is how do I change this to be able to run without the onedit?

EDIT: my range to move needs to be all rows in column A starting in row 3[image]

Comment: What will `e.source` and `e.range.rowStart` return? Whatever  you want it to return, hardcore it or send a `e` object with  your required data

Comment: I cannot figure out the rowStart portion. Can you better help me please.

Comment: What would be the row start position when you call the script from outside? What do you expect it to be? What do you want it to be? I can't pull a magic number out of thin air. This is more of a logic issue than a programming problem. When there's a edit, the edited range is moved. What range do you want to move, when there's no edit?

Comment: I need my range to start with row 3 finding the first row of data in column A3:A

Comment: [Edit] to add it to the question, preferably with some sample data tables or screenshots

Comment: If the first row that is going to move is not going to be anything other than row 3, you could simply replace `e.range.rowStart` as `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, The following replacements can be made:

- `e.source` -> `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`
- `e.range.rowStart` -> 3

Use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), so that it may run on both onEdit as well as calling without a parameter:

```
function archiveIVABPO(
  e = { source: SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), range: { rowStart: 3 } }
) {
//...Rest of your code
}
```